# How to output database data as separate integers in order to use them for an if-else condition?

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot seem to get the right database output with php, in order to use the output in a php if-elseif-else conditional statement.

this is my code:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 

mysql_select_db('patientdb');
$query = "SELECT status FROM clients";
$result = mysql_query($query);    

?>
```

I then added to see what the output would be with `print_r($result);`

the output is:

> Resource id #3

How can I get separate integers in order to use the output for a (php) if/elseif/else conditional statement?

Comment: try print_r($result)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: @Abhishek please see my question again. I tried it, now I get something: "Resource id #3"

Comment: follow below ans given by @Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll begin by saying the mysql_ functions are deprecated and should not be used. Instead you should be using mysqli_ or PDO.

mysql_query () returns a MySQL resource on success, and false on failure.

You need to store the resource and then loop through it to retrieve the required data, such as:

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 

mysql_select_db('patientdb');
$query = "SELECT status FROM clients";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!empty ($result)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['status'] . "<br />";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Dude, thank you. Also I did not know about the depreciation of the mysql_functions.